# Passing multiple parameters through url in android and getting them in PHP

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

In my Android application I have passed the sqlite data into remote mysql database using JSON over AsyncHttp protocol.
Now I want the data from Mysql database to SQLite database so that from server I am fetching the data and converting it to JSON.
Since server has many rows of data I need to fetch only my mobiles sqlite data so that I need to pass the variables and check if the data is mine or not rather than fetching all the users data.

How to pass the variables in the url so that while fetching only I want to search my users data and insert them to SQLITE database.
Here is my code

```
public void syncMySQLDBSQLite(){
            // Create AsycHttpClient object
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            // Http Request Params Object
            RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
            // Show ProgressBar
            prgDialog.show();
            // Make Http call to getusers.php
            client.post("http://10.0.2.2/tafapps/getuser.php", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String response) {
                        // Hide ProgressBar
                        prgDialog.hide();
                        // Update SQLite DB with response sent by getusers.php
                        updateSQLite(response);

                    }
                    // When error occured
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Throwable error, String content) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // Hide ProgressBar
                        prgDialog.hide();
                        if (statusCode == 404) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Requested resource not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else if (statusCode == 500) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong at server end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unexpected Error occcured! [Most common Error: Device might not be connected to Internet]",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
            });
        }

         public void updateSQLite(String response){
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> usersynclist;
                usersynclist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                // Create GSON object
                Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
                try {
                    // Extract JSON array from the response
                    JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, 5000).show();
                    System.out.println(arr.length());
                    // If no of array elements is not zero
                    if(arr.length() != 0){
                        // Loop through each array element, get JSON object which has userid and username
                        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                            // Get JSON object
                            JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);
                            System.out.println(obj.get("userId"));
                            System.out.println(obj.get("userName"));
                            db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("Hangman", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

                           // String id =  obj.get("userId").toString();
                             name =  obj.get("userName").toString();
                             email = obj.get("userEmail").toString();
                             phn = obj.get("userPhnum").toString();
                             plyd = obj.get("userPlayed").toString();
                             crct = obj.get("userCorrect").toString();
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), email, 5000).show();

                            db.execSQL("insert into scores(userName,userEmail,userPhnum,userPlayed,userCorrect)values('"+name+"','"+email+"','"+phn+"','"+plyd+"','"+crct+"')");
                        }
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+queryValues, 5000).show();
                        // Inform Remote MySQL DB about the completion of Sync activity by passing Sync status of Users
                        updateMySQLSyncSts(gson.toJson(usersynclist));
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTTP GET or POST requests.
GET example with parametrs:
http://example.com/tafapps/getuser.php?user=user1&user_age=21

In POST request this parametrs will be not visible inside URL and encoded instead inside request body.

You can use the parse_url() and parse_str() for parsing:

```
$parts = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parts['query'], $query);
echo $query['user'];
```

Or even better as I knew:

```
$user = $_GET['user']
```

[PHP Manual: Predefined _GET variable](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: can you please explain how to get the data from url in PHP side..?

Comment: Request parsing in PHP explained.